# How to add HTML to PHP Debug Bar indicator tooltip?

Tags: php, phpdebugbar

This question pertains to [PHP Debug Bar](http://phpdebugbar.com/).

I'm adding a custom `DataCollector` to PHP Debug Bar. I want to add some nicely formatted information to it when I mouse over it. For example,

```
public function getWidgets() {
    $name = $this->getName();
    $hg_changeset = rtrim(`/usr/local/bin/hg id -i`,"\n+") ?: '(unavailable)';
    $hg_branch = rtrim(`/usr/local/bin/hg id -b`,"\n") ?: '(unavailable)';
    return array(
        $name => array(
            "icon" => "leaf",
            "tooltip" => "Changeset: $hg_changeset\nBranch: $hg_branch",
            "map" => $name,
            "default" => json_encode("Unknown"),
        )
    );
}
```

Renders like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can put HTML in the `tooltip`? It seems to autoescape it.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can create your own Indicator [like this](http://phpdebugbar.com/docs/javascript-bar.html#custom-tabs-and-indicators),

```
var LinkIndicator = PhpDebugBar.DebugBar.Indicator.extend({

    tagName: 'a',

    render: function() {
        LinkIndicator.__super__.render.apply(this);
        this.bindAttr('href', function(href) {
            this.$el.attr('href', href);
        });
    }

});
```

You can throw that in its own file, and include it in your collector using the `DebugBar\DataCollector\AssetProvider` interface. I took a stab in the dark, there's a secret property on the `getWidgets` method that lets you specify a custom indicator:

```
public function getWidgets()
{
    return array(
        "nameOfMyWidget" => array(
            "icon" => "inbox",
            "indicator" => "LinkIndicator", // lets you specify the JS "class" you just created
            "map" => "nameOfMyWidget",
            "default" => "'xxx'"
        )
    );
}
```

**Update:** So it's not actually a secret, it's buried in the docs at the [bottom of this page](http://phpdebugbar.com/docs/rendering.html#the-javascript-object).